# Vue: Collect all (or some) form values simultaneously

Tags: forms, vue.js

I'm trying to understand if I can achieve with vue.js the same handy process I use to follow with vanilla/jquery to **collect simultaneously** all (or only some of) the form fields I need.

When dealing with forms usually I never submit them the old school way, instead, I add a class `my-update` to the form fields I want to send and then I loop them this way:

```
let objectToUpdate = {};
      $(".my-update").each(function(index, element) {
        objectToUpdate[$(this).data("db-field")] = $(this).val();
      });
```

Then I just pass the object to an Ajax POST call and send it to the backend API.
With Vue, it's way simple to get data since we have the property (usually called `data`) already available within the Vue instance but the problem is if I just send the `this.$data` it will catch not only the properties (all of them without choice) but also all methods included in the object (getter/setter, ...).

Do you have any best practice or suggestions to share to achieve the same I usually do with a couple of lines of jquery but in Vue?

Answer (score 1):

Usually in Vue form controls are binded to `data` via `v-model`. Let's say my Vue instance/component is like:

```
new Vue({
  data: {
    user: {
      name: '',
      surname: '',
      phone: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    send() {
      // send this.user through http
    }
  }
});
```

And my template is like:

```
<form @submit="send">
<input name="username" v-model="user.name" />
<input name="surname" v-model="user.surname" />
<input name="phone" v-model="user.phone" />
<button> send </button>
</form>
```

In such scenario, you have all the user information in your component/instance via `this.user`. You don't need to send `this.$data` at all if you create an object to manage your form fields (like `this.user` in this example).

Comment: Hi thanks a lot this is actually a great idea...I'm ashamed I did not think about it. Was just trying now and I achieved a partial good result using `Object.entries(this.$data)` but I will follow your example so I can differentiate semantically the information! Thanks again

Comment: It's common to overthink when transitioning from jQuery to a declarative framework like Vue, don't be ashamed! :-)